# How do I describe the two types of adjectives, terminologically?

Tags: adjectives, terminology

In adjectives there are two main groups:

**First Group**: adjectives that their 3 grades (base, comparative and superlative) are changed whether regularly (nice > nicer > nicest) or irregularly (good > better > best).

**Second group**:  adjectives that their 3 grades, are changed by adding "more" or "most" (e.g. "more expensive" or "most expensive" rather than *expensivier* or *expensiviest*)

Then my question is, how are these two groups distinguished **terminologically**?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "terminologically"?

Comment: Yes, of course. I meant to ask how they are frequently called in the grammar terminology field.

Comment: You mean "what terms are used describe these groups?"

Comment: Yes. What are they called (rather than "how they are called") in the grammar terminology. or is short as you said "what are the terms for these groups". 

Comment: They all enter into the system of 'grade' by comparison, the first group marked by inflection, the second marked analytically. So the terms you are looking for are **inflectionally gradable for comparison** and **analytically gradable for comparison**.

Comment: The answer to this is: there is no way to distinguish them terminologically. And: one thing is being able to use them and another is answering as Mary-Lou A has done, which is very good, but only used in linguistics as a field and not in English language learning per se. Also, the "groups" in the question are  incorrect.

Comment: Of course they can be distinguished. When categorising adjectives that enter the system of grade by means of comparison, there are two sub-types: those that are inflectionally gradable and those that are analytically gradable. They correspond to the OP's first and second groups respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* the OP is asking how to classify the different types of adjectives. Apologies if I have misunderstood.

Basically, adjectives can be classified by the number of syllables. The rules governing disyllabic adjectives are a bit complicated to go into any great detail but see this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145683/conundrum-cleverer-or-more-clever-simpler-or-more-simple-etc) and the answers posted on EL&U if you are curious.

Adjectives consisting of one syllable are **[monosyllabic](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/monosyllabic)**

They can also be called **[one syllable adjectives](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/comparative-and-superlative/)**.

Adjectives with two syllables are **[bisyllabic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bisyllabic)**  or
**[disyllabic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/disyllabic)**

Or they can simply be called **[two syllable adjectives](http://www.onestopenglish.com/methodology/teaching-tips/ask-the-experts/grammar-questions/grammar-two-syllable-comparatives/146356.article)**

Adjectives with three syllables are  **[trisyllabic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trisyllabic)** or **three syllable adjectives**

> - In English, the comparative can be formed either synthetically (prouder) or analytically (more proud). Quirk et al. (1985: 461) identify word length as the major factor in the distribution, suggesting that the **synthetic comparative is formed by monosyllabic adjectives**, while **trisyllabic or longer adjectives form the analytic comparative**.
> - **Disyllabic adjectives are said to exhibit variation**. While word length does seem to have a strong effect, exceptions such as *more apt* or
>     *trustworthier* indicate that more factors have to be considered.
>
> *[The English comparative - Phonology and Usage](https://web.stanford.edu/dept/linguistics/linginst/nsf-workshop/Hilpert_abstract.pdf)*

Comment: Thank you @Mari-Lou for your answer. But honestly I didn't ask how to  classify the different types of adjectives. I ask very specifically about one classification of adjectives while I mentioned the most common classifications (regular Vs. irregular. long Vs short) see here for example: http://vocabularyhome.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Regular-and-Irregular-Adverbs.png and here: https://image.slidesharecdn.com/copiadeadjectivesincomparision-130326105336-phpapp02/95/copia-de-adjectives-in-comparision-1-638.jpg?cb=1364295257. I'm sorry for that I wasn't clear and for the trouble.

Comment: I think Mari has answered the question here: *adjectives that form the comparative **synthetically*** and *adjectives that form the comparative **analytically***.

Comment: @subtle_sibling well "short and long adjectives" (as per your link) is not far off from being the truth, but perhaps a little too simplistic. For example, would you say that "boring" was a short or long adjective? To me it's short but if I count the number of syllables I understand that it belongs to that tricky   area where a disyllabic adjective can either follow the one syllable or the three syllable "rule", so then I have to see if it ends with the letter "Y" if it does, choosing the right comparative form is *easier* :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm very confused about the definition of long and short, because in some of the materials I saw that they consider 2 syllables as short and some of them consider only one syllable as short. "Cambridge grammar and vocabulary for first" for example doesn't use at all in these terms of short and long. instead, it uses one, two, and three / four syllables.

Comment: Continue: The exceptions, as I understand, are in the two syllable words that normally ('a few' as the mentioned book calls them) they are not in the -er and -est system. Exceptions are two syllable words that end in -le (simple) or -er (clever) or -y (angry, funny, tidy)

Comment: @subtle_sibling  *Long and short adjectives* are simplifications as you have realised. Instead, look at the number of syllables an adjective or an adverb has. The ones with two syllables can sometimes take the suffixes **-er**, **-est** or the words **more** and **most**. For example, "commoner", "commonest" and "cleverer", "cleverest"  and/or "more clever/common" "most clever/common". But don't worry too much over these exceptions. If you follow the rule about the comparative with 3 syllable adjectives, it's never wrong.

Comment: In the meantime I found a respected reference that refer to both in the same terms, so I can say that your answer is what I looked for. Thank you! https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/english-language-and-linguistics/article/determinants-of-the-syntheticanalytic-variation-across-english-comparatives-and-superlatives-1/2FCA500541B837B876057DBCC67765F4